# How to multiply "bottom" by a constant number

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

Sorry for this primitive question; but I've just started using caffe.
I want to multiple output of a layer by a constant:
top = bottom * k

any ideas This is what I have tried so far: (for example costant = 0.5)

```
expParam = {power: 1
            scale: 0.5
            shift: 0}
L.Exp(bottom, exp_param=expParam, in_place=False)
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks Nico. I added the code.

Comment: look at "Scale" layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`"Scale"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/scale.html) layer:

```
L.Scale(bottom, scale_param={'filler': {'type': 'constant', 'value': 0.5}}, 
        param={'lr_mult': 0, 'decay_mult': 0})
```

Note that by default `"Scale"` layer *learns* the scale factor. If you want it to remain fixed you need to set `lr_mult` to zero.